# trying to add one entity, but also insert another entity to db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have three entities: Product, Item(consist of one product and no. of product that is purchased by customer) and Factor as below:

```
public class Factor
{
    [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int FactorId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual System.Guid TrackingCode { set; get; }
    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string StatusOfFactor { set; get; }
    [Required, DataType(DataType.EmailAddress), StringLength(200)]
    public string EmailOfFactor { set; get; }
    // price before discount
    public virtual double PriceOfFactor { set; get; }
    public virtual double DiscountOfFactor { set; get; }
    [StringLength(3000,MinimumLength =0)]
    public virtual string GeneralDescription { set; get; }
    public virtual List<Item> Items { set; get; }
}


public class Item
{
    //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ItemId { set; get; }
    public int Count { set; get; }
    // 1 -> 1 relationship between product and Item
    public virtual Product Product { set; get; }
    // * -> * relationship between Item and Factor
    public virtual List<Factor> Factors { set; get; }
}


public class Product
{
    [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int ProductId { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public virtual string NameFa { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [Range(0, 990000000)]
    public virtual double Price { set; get; }
    // many->many relationship category and product
    public virtual List<Category> Categories { set; get; }
    //public virtual List<Factor> Factors { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { set; get; }
}
```

the relationship between entities are as follow:
1 -> 1 in Product-Item and * -> * in Item-Factor

```
public class ProductConfig:EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductConfig() {
        // one to one relationship between product and item
        HasOptional(p => p.Item).WithRequired(i => i.Product);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class FactorConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Factor>
{
    public FactorConfig( ) {
       HasMany(p => p.Items)
      .WithMany(p => p.Factors)
      .Map(c => {
          c.ToTable("ItemsFactors");
          c.MapLeftKey("FactorID");
          c.MapRightKey("ItemID");
      });
    }
}
```

when i Insert a factor to db, another product also add to table of product!!!
here is a code for inserting factor to db:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult RegisterFactor( [Bind(Include = "FactorId,TrackingCode,RegistrationDate,PaymentSucceed,PaymentIdOfBank,PaymentDate,StatusOfFactor,EmailOfFactor,TranmissionSucceed,TransmissionDate,PriceOfFactor,DiscountOfFactor,GeneralDescription,IsReturned,ReturnedDate,ReturnedDescription")]Factor factor )  
{  
    {
        // Session consist of Items and Items consist of Products
        List<Item> purchasedItems =
        (List<Item>)Session[Constants.SHOPPINGBAG];
        double totalPriceBeforeDiscount = 0.0d; 
        double totalDiscount = 0.0d;            
        double totalPriceAfterDiscount = 0.0; 
        //
        Guid trackingCode = Guid.NewGuid();
        factor.Items = new List<Item>();
        if ( purchasedItems == null )
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        foreach ( Item item in purchasedItems )
        {
            if ( item.Product != null )
            {
                factor.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        // allocate data to factor
        factor.PriceOfFactor = totalPriceBeforeDiscount;
        factor.DiscountOfFactor = totalDiscount;
        factor.PaymentDate = DateTime.Now;
        factor.RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now;
        factor.TrackingCode = trackingCode;
        if ( ModelState.IsValid )
        {
            //db.Factors.AsNoTracking();
            db.Products.AsNoTracking();
            db.Factors.Add(factor);
            db.SaveChanges();
            EmptyShoppingCart();
            return View("RegisterFactorSucceed", factor);
        }
        return View(factor);
    }
}
```

It is really awkward (for me). why was happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'ProductConfig' is saying whenever Item has 'product' then the same should be added into Product table. Here is the modified code.

ProductConfig class

```
public class ProductConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductConfig()
    {
        // one to one relationship between product and item
        HasOptional(p => p.Item).WithOptionalDependent(i => i.Product);
    }
}
```

If you change Item.Product to null then it won't  add to Product table.

```
foreach (Item item in purchasedItems)
        {
            if (item.Product != null)
            {
                factor.Items.Add(item);
                item.Product = null;//Setting Product to null
            }
        }
```

Comment: really thanks for your response.  Product class is dependent upon Item class. i.e. each Item must have one or more products but it is not true for product. does my relationship between item and product correct?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that your Factor object has a reference to a product in memory that you are passing back to EF. So EF is interpreting this as a new product and adding it along with the factor.

You need to either..

1. Not pass a populated product in memory along with the factor you are adding and link it using Ids
2. Make sure you load the existing product you want to attach the factor to from the database with tracking before the save.

I think https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn166926.aspx might help.

Comment: Dear grrrrrrrrrrrrr, thanks for your nice response. I think that this is caused by the 1st note that you send. but HOW should I remove populated product in memory?

Comment: You need to look into using Ids to reference other entities in EF. They massively simplify the situation. I think https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn166926.aspx will explain more.